# adding comma if more than one item value from custom tag

Tags: php, tags

Here is my code - I would to modify. i added "echo ".&nbsp";" which adds a space and full stop after every value. However it will be added even if a value is not more than one. I would like modify code to put a comma and space only if the value is more than one. Thanks

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'book-author' ); 
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'book-author' );
                    if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
                    continue;
                echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                    echo ".&nbsp";
                } 
            ?>
```

Comment: Use `implode()` to concatenate all the elements of an array with a delimiter between them.

Comment: can you demonstrate for me for my specific scenaria

Answer (score 1):

Put all your strings in an array, then use `implode()` to combine them with a delimiter.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'book-author' ); 
$links = [];
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'book-author' );
    if( !is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
        $links[] = '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    }
} 
echo implode('.&nbsp;', $links);
```